# R - arrow, duckdb and dbplyr --- memory error after creating several tbl_duckdb_connections

Tags: r, duckdb

I am working with large datasets using {arrow, duckdb, dbplyr}.

I am experiencing some issues after opening a bunch of tbl_duckdb_connections. I do this as I need to manipulate and join them until I have only one tbl_duckdb_connection.

When I finally try to pull some data from the final duckdb object (like a performing a slice and uploading it, or even just counting the number of rows), it takes forever and I get an "Out of Memory" error, which also says that "Database is launched in in-memory mode and no temporary directory is specified".

What am I doing wrong?

My code looks something like this, but there are more joins involved:

```
db1 <- arrow::open_dataset(source = paste0(path, "data1.csv"), format = "csv") %>%
   arrow::to_duckdb()

db2 <- arrow::open_dataset(source = paste0(path, "data2.csv"), format = "csv") %>%
   arrow::to_duckdb()

db3 <- inner_join(bd1, bd2, by = "id") %>%
   collect()
```

This is strange because even counting the number of rows in db3 using the following code takes a long time and gives the same error:

```
db3 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(num = n())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arrow::to_duckdb()` calls the private `arrow_duck_connection()` function that basically calls `duckdb::duckdb()`, with default args, creating an in-memory DB.

The error message you get (Out of memory) seems to indicate thatthe duckdb DB runs out of memory.

You could then create explicitly a duckdb connection `x` using duckdb::duckdb("mydir"), and pass it to `arrow::to_duckdb(x)`.